# Qt QWebView network timeout values and signals

Tags: qt, networking, webkit, timeout, qtwebkit

How can a `QWebView` be configured to lower network timeout values - so that in the event of the network failure the `loadFinished(bool ok)` signal can be reached sooner, obviously, with a `false` value and an appropriate error condition set?

Bonus points for handling different timeouts differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard errors and successful page loading will trigger loadFinished the same way as before, but a custom timer will stop the webpage loading and trigger loadFinished with ok=False

```
class Browser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_view.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)

        self._error = None

    def perform(self, url, timeout_value=30):
        request = QNetworkRequest()
        request.setUrl(QUrl(url))

        self.timeout_timer = QTimer()
        self.timeout_timer.timeout.connect(self._request_timed_out)

        self.timeout_timer.start(timeout_value * 1000)
        self.web_view.load(request)

    def _request_timed_out(self):
        self._error = 'Custom request timeout value exceeded.'
        self.timeout_timer.stop()
        self.web_view.stop()
        self.loadFinished.emit(False)

    def _load_finished(self, ok):
        pass
        # ok is now False, and self._error contains a custom error message
```

Comment: It is a valid workaround - could potentially be even more encapsulated by subclassing QWebView.. but still, I can't believe they hardcoded timeouts on all the select() calls on the network sockets, now do they?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, as I did not find anything helpful in the API documentation regarding the timeout values...